# How to update data in a database object from a list (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I update data in the database. When expanding the Books list, you have to constantly edit the code (`SomeValue1, SomeValue2, SomeValue3`, etc.) Is it possible to immediately pass an object from the list to the found line?

```
using (var db = new MyContextDB())
{
    var result = db.Books.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BookNumber == bookNumber);

    if (result != null)
    {
        result.SomeValue = "Some new value";
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the object in the list also a Book?

Comment: Why do you have to "constantly edit the code?"